# Material design 3 ripple opacity

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android

Currently, MD3 uses an opacity/alpha of I think 50% of the specified ripple color for their pressed state on components. Is there any way to change the opacity of it?

This is what I currently use to test the ripple effect on material buttons in MD3:

```xml
<style name="Widget.App.Button" parent="Widget.Material3.Button">
    <item name="rippleColor">@color/black_000</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/button_filled_foreground_color</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/white_1000</item>
</style>
```

The button:

```xml
<Button
    style="@style/Widget.App.Button"
    android:id="@+id/create_account_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/create_account"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/log_in_button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

In this example the background color is white and the ripple effect will be gray. How can I change the ripple opacity to 100% so that it results in the ripple effect being black? I use `1.5.0-beta01` material version.

Comment: Can you please add the code example so people can help you with that reference?

Comment: I don't think its possible even with the code. So you probably need to create a Custom ripple drawable class . default alpha is set to 0.5f . check the source for class `RippleBackground`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't think you can change the ripple color opacity because it is decided by the framework. It is handled by the [RippleDrawable](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable.java#L865) class for devices with lollipop and above and [RippleDrawableCompat](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/7665730a0befae42a15c89ba5c1082a5e98442ad/lib/java/com/google/android/material/ripple/RippleDrawableCompat.java) class for pre lollipop devices.

> Ripple opacity will be determined by the Android framework when available. Otherwise, this color will be overlaid on the button at a 50% opacity when button is pressed.

From [MaterialButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton#:%7E:text=Ripple%20opacity%20will%20be%20determined%20by%20the%20Android%20framework%20when%20available.%20Otherwise%2C%20this%20color%20will%20be%20overlaid%20on%20the%20button%20at%20a%2050%25%20opacity%20when%20button%20is%20pressed.) documentation.

If you really want solid black color ripple , you can try creating a custom drawable with selector tag and set it as background in your button with backgroundTint as "null". However i don't recommend doing this.